# Replace old Spring Boot Jar with new one

Tags: spring-boot, service, jar

I'm running a spring boot executable jar as a service under Linux and it works fine.
My question is, there is a way to replace the running jar with new jar without stopping and rerunning the service?

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, it is impossible to reload spring-boot jar in production environment.
I guess your final goal is to "hotswap" your application without user notified. Thanks to service discovery, you can do this by:

1. Start your new application and keep the old ones running.
2. After the new one started and registered in service discovery server, shutdown the old ones.

That's how we do upgrade of our services, and Docker saves us a lot of time.